# Adding library in CMake with many subfolder

Tags: c++, c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico, c-header

I am starting with the raspberry pi pico and the visual studio code in windows. I am practising with the pico examples coming in the SDK V1.5. What I want to try in this example is to add a new level of folder with an  .C and .h files in it. The purpose of this is I want to try a sensor mcp for that the folders structure is something like.

```
/pico-example
     -CMakeLists.txt
      /i2c
          -CMakeList.txt
          - i2c.c
          /Sensor9600
              -mcp9600.c
              -mcp9600.h
      /spi
      /gpio
```

I tried to have a executable from i2c that call main and include the sensor as well.

The Cmakelist from the pico-example is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# Pull in SDK (must be before project)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

include(pico_extras_import_optional.cmake)

project(pico_examples C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "1.3.0")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Raspberry Pi Pico SDK version 1.3.0 (or later) required. Your version is ${PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING}")
endif()

set(PICO_EXAMPLES_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Initialize the SDK
pico_sdk_init()

include(example_auto_set_url.cmake)
# Add blink example
add_subdirectory(blink)

# Add hello world example
add_subdirectory(hello_world)

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format          # int != int32_t as far as the compiler is concerned because gcc has int32_t as long int
        -Wno-unused-function # we have some for the docs that aren't called
        -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
        )

# Hardware-specific examples in subdirectories:
add_subdirectory(adc)
add_subdirectory(clocks)
add_subdirectory(cmake)
add_subdirectory(divider)
add_subdirectory(dma)
add_subdirectory(flash)
add_subdirectory(gpio)
add_subdirectory(i2c)
add_subdirectory(interp)
add_subdirectory(multicore)
add_subdirectory(picoboard)
add_subdirectory(pico_w)
add_subdirectory(pio)
add_subdirectory(pwm)
add_subdirectory(reset)
add_subdirectory(rtc)
add_subdirectory(spi)
add_subdirectory(system)
add_subdirectory(timer)
add_subdirectory(uart)
add_subdirectory(usb)
add_subdirectory(watchdog)
add_subdirectory(betagecko)
```

I tried to create One Cmakefile.txt for the i2c folder

```
add_executable(i2c
        i2c.c
        )

# pull in common dependencies and additional i2c hardware support
target_link_libraries(i2c pico_stdlib hardware_i2c 
                         mcp9600)


                        
# enable usb output, disable uart output
pico_enable_stdio_usb(i2c 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(i2c 0)

# create map/bin/hex file etc.
pico_add_extra_outputs(i2c)

# add url via pico_set_program_url
example_auto_set_url(i2c)

    
add_subdirectory(Sensor9600)
```

Then the file inside the Sensor9600 folder CMakeList.txt

I tried

```
add_library(mcp9600 mcp9600.c)
target_sources(mcp9600PUBLIC mcp9600.h)
target_include_directories(mcp9600 INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I tried modified the I2c.c and it works the probles is when I tried to add other level of folder. I read some solution and it did not works for me so I am doing something really wrong.

Could you help me with this?

Edit: The compiler can not find the file mcp9600.h, so I think I am doing something wrong with Cmake

Comment: Can you try `add_library(mcp9600 mcp9600.c mcp9600.h)`  and delete the line with `target_sources(...`? Should be fine. If not, it would be interesting just *where* the compiler cannot find the header file. The full error message would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) How do you do the `#include`? Do you want to `#include <mcp9600.h>`? Or do you want to `#include <Sensor9600/mcp9600.h>`? 2) If the include error is happening in your mcp9600.c file, then the problem is the fact that you used `INTERFACE` in `target_include_directories`. If that header contains the interface of your library, you should use `PUBLIC` instead of `INTERFACE`, and if not, you should use `PRIVATE`. You use `INTERFACE` when the target itself doesn't need that include directory, but targets that link with it do.

Comment: There's also the obvious typo in `target_sources(mcp9600PUBLIC mcp9600.h)` (missing blank before `PUBLIC`) this would cause CMake to fire an error like "unknown target". But, as I wrote above, get rid of that line completely.